# How to show status about submitted form when using POST-Redirect-GET pattern?

Tags: django, django-forms

The POST-Redirect-GET pattern is recommended when submitting forms, in order to void resending the POST data if the user does a refresh.  This may be done in the view handling the POST data with code like:

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            interesting_information = 'Feedback after form submit'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

But using this scheme, how is it possible to show `interesting_information` to the user, which may for example be status information based on the submitted form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Django's [Messages Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/) to set a message in your form handling view:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success(request, 'Feedback after form submit')
```

and display it to the user on your /thanks/ page:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

You'll need to make sure you follow the steps in the "[Enabling messages]"(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages) section of the docs first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to [The messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/); I was not aware of this Django feature.